# Uninstall .NET Framework update

Tags: windows-update, iis

Today I've updated my Windows with the latest updates.
After these updates my IIS server doesn't work correctly.
Each time I open my website I get this:

> An unhandled win32 exception occurred in w3wp.exe [8844].
>
> The **Just-In-Time debugger** was launched without necessary security
>   permissions. To debug this process, the Just-In-Time debugger must be
>   run as an Administrator. Would you like to debug this process?

Here are all updates that were installed today:
[image]

I think I receive JIT error because of this update:

> Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6 and 4.6 RC on Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 for x64 (KB3083185)

My question is how to uninstall this update?

I've tried to *"Open Installed Updates by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking Programs, and then, under Programs and Features, clicking View installed updates."*, but I don't see this update there

Comment: Refer the similar thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589029/an-unhandled-win32-exception-occurred-in-w3wp-exe

Comment: No, that's another issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I could uninstall this update using these instructions:

*"Open Installed Updates by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking Programs, and then, under Programs and Features, clicking View installed updates."*

The name of the update was different but I could find it by "KB3083185".

And yes - this update broke my IIS. I have uninstalled this update and now it work fine